# Angularjs injecting $resource into factory for Testing with jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I am writing my unit tests to test factory developed as below

```
angular.module("MyApp.Factory",[]).factory("factory",function($resource, baseUrl) {
    return {
        someService: function () {
            return $resource(baseUrl + "/someUri");
        }
    };
});
```

jasmine spec for the same

```
describe("My App Factory Tests", function () {

        var $factory;

        beforeEach(function () {

            module("MyApp.Factory");

            inject(function (factory) {
                $factory = factory;
            });

        });

        it("Factory must be defined", function () {
            expect($factory).toBeDefined();
        });


    });
```

but i end up with the below error from the jasmine html test page

`Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- eligibilityService`

Please suggest the right way to test the factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngResource` is defined in the separate module. Please check the documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource
In other words you have to include `<script src="angular-resource.js">` and add `ngResource` dependency to `MyApp.Factory` module - `angular.module("MyApp.Factory", ["ngResource"])`.

ps. in the specs you could surround service name with underscores so that we can locally assign a local variable of the same name as the service. For example:

```
var factory;

beforeEach(function () {

  module("MyApp.Factory");

  inject(function (_factory_) {
    factory = _factory_;
  });

});
```

According to angularjs coding standards `$` should not be used for naming custom directives.

Comment: what is the simplest way to instantiate a factory for a unit test?

Comment: just inject it to the spec, for example: `it("does the magic", inject(function(myService) { expect(myService.trick()).toBe(true); }));